# extract url domain and get the last part

Tags: jquery

```
domain.com/name/directory/brand
domain.com/name/directory/design
domain.com/name/directory/design/123-456-7
```

what i want to get is all the string after directory/

```
brand
design
design/123-456-7
```

this is my url , and my intention is to get all the string after directory/ but i dont want to split cause i have some more url to extra using the same function.

so no matter what url it put in , i will remove the domain.com/name/directory/ and get the last url.

Comment: You can use `split()` i.e. `"domain.com/name/directory/design/123-456-7".split('directory/')[1]`

Comment: like how ?   var path = window.location.pathname;
  var extractPath = path.split('director‌​y/');

Comment: i got undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do it with a regex

```
urls = [
    'domain.com/name/directory/brand',
    'domain.com/name/directory/design',
    'domain.com/name/directory/design/123-456-7',
    'domain.com/name/directory/brand/foo/bar/'
];

delimiter = 'directory\/';

results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    results.push(urls[i].match(new RegExp(delimiter+'(.*?)[\s\/]*$'))[1]);
}

alert(results);
```

Comment: Thank you ~ but one more question i have a slash at the back , how do i remove it as well ?

Comment: /brand/ <<<<< the last slash , can you teach me how to remove it as well ?

Comment: I modified the example above, to remove trailing slashes